# Please clarify the 'What topics can I ask about here?' section of the help center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

I would like to have [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - identification, diagnosis or management of plant diseases, pests, or weeds,

changed to reflect on our scope of identifying. It only includes [diseases](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification+diseases), [pests](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification+pests), and [weeds](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification+weeds), while we also will identify [trees](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification+trees), [shrubs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification+shrubs), [flowers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification+flowers), [wildflowers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification+wildflowers), [houseplants](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification+houseplants). and other things.

This post is mostly the result of [this](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/species-identification-questions/343#343) meta post on biology.se, where there is some confusion as to what's on-topic identification-wise there as well as here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the risk of making the "on-topic" list too long to be easily digestible, I'd split that bullet point into two: one for identification and one for diagnosis/treatment of problems.

As you've noted, we welcome lots of plant identification questions, though some types I don't see as being completely appropriate — seaweed or lichen, for example — since they wouldn't be part of a typical garden, or would be something that you'd want to remove rather than cultivate — mosses in a lawn being an obvious candidate here.

I don't see animal identification as belonging here, except in the context of the animal affecting the garden in some way, in which case it would also fall under pest control:

My suggested wording for the "identification" bullet:

> - identification of plants — trees, shrubs, flowers, wildflowers — cultivated or growing in the garden or as a houseplant, or of animals that are affecting your garden or houseplants.

With identification handled separately, the other bullet point would address the "problem" aspects of the original wording:

> - gardening problems such as diagnosis and management of plant diseases and pests or methods for controlling weeds.